# Three black crows followed by a three inside up in an uptrend

Tags: stocks, investing, stock-analysis, stock-exchanges, technical-analysis

I am new to stock trading and is interested in reading trends. Recently, I looked at ANTM with a three black crows trend followed by a three inside up trend on an uptrend. From what I have learned,

Three black crows: is a sign that we  should sell, unless it is an uptrend.

Three inside up: is a sign of bullish reversal trend, meaning that bullish will become bearish.

My question is: What does this pattern combo mean? Does this mean that there will be a down trend based on this technical analysis pattern combo? Please do fix any misconceptions that I have in any of the patterns. I am new to stock trading, any help would be great.

You can see the chart here:
[image]

Comment: If it meant anything with consistency, don't you suppose everyone would cash in on it?

Comment: @HartCO What I am trying to figure out is how the trend "usually" acts after that kind of pattern. It defenitely wont be consistent, but would'nt it act at least as a signifier?

Comment: The only value in this pattern is if there are  enough people who believe in it, they recognize it and then they act accordingly.  Otherwise it's just a pretty pattern that someone has  identified in order to sell you the dream.  However, past performance is no guarantee of future results.

Comment: @Squish Every piece of information about trends is already priced in. If this meant you should buy, even 51% of the time, then people would buy... but all the people buying would mean you should sell.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome new user,

It would be meaningless to discuss the arcane **details** of some particular supposed stock method on a "general" list like this which provides "answers".

You'd have to find a group that literally discusses nothing but candlestick charts.  Amongst that group, you would get broad-ranging discussion on whatever the issue is. **There's no "answer" per se.** It would be like asking "Who's better, Tom Brady or Drew Brees?" It's a discussion point.

Do note that:

1. "Candelstick charting" is merely ***one line of thinking*** on markets.  Note that many people feel it is utter, utter, nonsense, so any detail questions would be doubly-nonsensical. You give the impression that you feel candlestick issues are sort of "definitive" and "how one trades".
2. If you trade you will lose money.

Again, to discuss (there are no "answers") the minor details of (for example) "candlestick charting" you will need to find a **discussion** group on that specific topic.

As an aside if, for some reason (why?), you are interested in "candlestick charting", study the Nison book [link](https://www.thriftbooks.com/w/japanese-candlestick-charting-techniques-a-contemporary-guide-to-the-ancient-investment-techniques-of-the-far-east_steve-nison/247001/) (unless you happen to read Japanese), everything else on the matter is totally pointless.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Since I am talking about technical analysis, What I want to know is based on previous charts (from the past), what usually happen after this kind of pattern occur. I am not asking for a discussion, just some concrete evidence of what has happened in the past.

Comment: Hi @Squish , right, that is precisely what I am describing.  The exact question, you just stated, in your comment, is: precisely, a matter of discussion.  I have a firm opinion on it, and other "candlestick charters" have a firm opinion on it; the 10-million-$ a year budget "technical analysis departments" at banks have an opinion on it, and so on; your assertion that there is a "scientific fixed answer" is (unfortunately) simply wrong.  What I explained applies to exactly what you are asking in the comment.